# security error while get transaction details with PHP cURL for paypal

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, paypal-sandbox

This is my code:-

```
$info =  'USER=[insyttest.gmail.com]'
. '&PWD=[YWZXKCGZHQB7R]'
. '&SIGNATURE=[ACt7UQvTwN3aH00Hh1V5A1sVS5xTtjahz.k8T1fcHjjgqwj]'
. '&VERSION=94'
. '&METHOD=GetTransactionDetails'
. '&TRANSACTIONID=[7A705084TL972213C]'
. '&STARTDATE=2021-03-01T05:38:48Z'
. '&ENDDATE=2021-07-07T05:38:48Z';

$curl = curl_init('https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $info);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$result = curl_exec($curl);

parse_str($result, $result);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

This is the response:-

```
 Array
 (
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2021-05-06T08:52:15Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => f5b6b6f7a2f90
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 94
    [BUILD] => 55101542
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10002
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Security error
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Security header is not valid
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
)
```

Can anyone help me where I am wrong?
I am searching for too much but still not able to find a perfect solution for that.
I also check the all related question of StackOverflow so please don't mention them this is the code from there but not anyone code working for me

i am using this method in WordPress site

thanx in advance for your help.

Comment: _"I also check the all related question of StackOverflow so please don't mention them"_ - If find a duplicate question, we will mention it. We have _no clue_ which you've looked at or why they didn't work for you.

Comment: Are those real credentials? If yes, then delete this question, post a new question where those credentials removed/masked. You should also change those credentials ASAP since you've just shared them with the world. Even if you edit this question, anyone can see them in the edit history. Never ever give away credentials anywhere!

Comment: its not a real creadential

Comment: can you please check why having a security error?

Comment: Before we start digging, update your question to include what posts you've already read and what you've tried so we don't sit here wasting time suggesting things you've already tested (since you explicitly told us not to.)

Answer (score 1):

These lines are problematic

```
$info =  'USER=[insyttest.gmail.com]'
. '&PWD=[YWZXKCGZHQB7R]'
. '&SIGNATURE=[ACt7UQvTwN3aH00Hh1V5A1sVS5xTtjahz.k8T1fcHjjgqwj]'
. '&TRANSACTIONID=[7A705084TL972213C]'
```

Ensure you are using a valid USER/PWD/SIGNATURE from https://www.paypal.com/api , and that there is no `[` or `]` character in what you are transmitting for those values.

The transaction ID must also not include `[` or `]`.